# assigning multiple css class to dropdown select based on php mysql query result value

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, css

im trying to implement jquery chained (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained). 
css class will be based from query row result.  see below info.

```
<select name="product_type">  
<option value="desktop">DESKTOP</option>
<option value="laptop">LAPTOP</option> 
<option value="smartphone">SMARTPHONE</option> 

<select name="device_type">  
<option value="dell" class="desktop laptop">DELL</option>
<option value="nokia" class="smartphone">NOKIA</option>
<option value="lenovo" class="desktop laptop smartphone">LENOVO</option>  


<select name="model_type">  
<option value="optiplex" class="dell">OPTIPLEX</option>
<option value="xps" class="dell">XPS</option>
<option value="Gseries" class="lenovo">GSERIES</option>  
<option value="Thinkcenter" class="lenovo">THINKCENTER</option>   
<option value="Thinkpad" class="lenovo">THINKPAD</option> 
<option value="Vide" class="lenovo">VIBE</option>
```

all these dropdown list are generated from mysql query using foreach loop,
Now my problem is HOW CAN I ADD THE MULTIPLE CLASS.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Echo the class when you build the select elements.

Comment: You can either echo it if you're using php to build the page, or you can add it with jQuery by calling to following: $('select[name="model_type]"').addClass('yourClass');